# Which pattern to use to get me Puzzle Structure

Tags: design-patterns

i'm looking for pattern to implement in puzzle game. i did
the puzzle and have puzzle parts that are programmed as components. 
i have Components factory that returns me the puzzle parts .

now im looking for Puzzle Structure pattern. for example:
in my main scene i want to be able to call puzzle "A1".
and it will return me the constructed puzzle from the puzzle parts.
i need to save states of each constructed puzzle.
which pattern will be the best for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the composite pattern which is a structural pattern since you are composing (using has-a relationships) and it would be convenient to apply actions (like save) hierarchically to the composite and the parts at the same time.

When you want to add features to existing parts or puzzles you should consider using the decorator pattern which is also a structural pattern .